# RANSAC algorithm using scikit-learn's RANSACRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, ransac

I tried to use the code below for fitting a robust regression model using `RANSAC`

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor
ransac = RANSACRegressor(LinearRegression(),
                        max_trials=100,
                        min_samples=50,
                        residual_metric=lambda x: np.sum(np.abs(x), axis=1),
                        residual_threshold=5.0,
                        random_state=0)
ransac.fit(X,y)
```

And I get the following error below:

```
TypeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-832d8b5d351b> in <module>
      5                         residual_metric=lambda x: np.sum(np.abs(x), axis=1),
      6                         residual_threshold=5.0,
----> 7                         random_state=0)
      8 ransac.fit(X,y)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'residual_metric'
```

Can you help me know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you got this code that was using an old version of ransac. The input residual_metric is [deprecated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5497). If you run without that, it works ok:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor, LinearRegression
ransac = RANSACRegressor(LinearRegression(),
                        max_trials=100,
                        min_samples=50,
                        residual_threshold=5.0,
                        random_state=0)

ransac

RANSACRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression(), min_samples=50,
                random_state=0, residual_threshold=5.0)
```